# Comparing some function to the typical $\log(z)$ for some complex $z$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm confused as to what the problem is really asking for, and how I would approach something like this. Would I want to compare this function to the log properties of a complex number? Or am I thinking in the wrong way? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Let $G(z)$ be the continuous branch of $\log z$ defined on $\mathbb C$ cut along
the positive part of the $x$-axis and determined by the condition that $\log (-1) = \pi$.
Describe its range and prove that it is 1-1.

Comment: Hint: parametrise the plane with the cut as $z = re^{i\theta }$, $r>0$, $0 < \theta  < 2\pi$. Then $G(z) = \log r + i\theta$.

Comment: So would the range, because log(-1) = pi, be from 0 to 2pi? How would I show that this is 1-1? Also, I guess I'm confused about branching and such. I'm not sure what the difference between this and Logz (principal branch) is; is it simply what range is being dictated by the negative x-axis?

Comment: The range will be $\left\{ z : 0<\operatorname{Im} z <2\pi \right\}$. When considering the principal branch, you perform the cut along the *negative* axis. The logarithm is a multivalued function and its natural domain is a [Riemann surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#The_associated_Riemann_surface).